# Перевод строки форматного вида в Double

Tags: java

Есть строка такого вида: `6.356909871101D-04`. Как конвертировать ее в `Double` в Java? Пробывал через `Double.parse` и `Double.valueOf`, безрезультатно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> есть строка такого вида: 6.356909871101D-04

[Экспоненциальная форма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) числа обычно записывается через `E`, а не через `D`. Поэтому можно заменить символ `D` на `E` с помощью метода [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-):

```
.replace('D', 'E')
```

Полный код ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/3A7pbA)):

```
String s = "6.356909871101D-04";
double x = Double.valueOf(s.replace('D', 'E'));
System.out.println(x);
```